# Local variable name is never read ? What should i do?

Tags: java

And it has a comment that the local variable name is never read . Please help I am almost done with it :) thanks for your help . I'm using Dr.Java IDE .

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class information {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name ;
        String course;
        char gender;
        int yearLevel;
        int age;

        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        name  = input.nextLine();


        System.out.print("Enter your gender [M/F]: ");
        gender  = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

        while(gender!= 'M' && gender!= 'F'){
            System.out.println("Error: type only M or F");
            System.out.println("Re-enter your gender [M/F]: ");
            gender  = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        }


        System.out.print("Enter your course: "); // BSCS, BSIT or BSIS
        course  = input.nextLine();

        while( course.equals("BSCS") || course.equals("BSIT") || course.equals("BSIS")){
            System.out.println("Error: type only BSCS,BSIT, or BSIS");
            System.out.println("Re-enter your course: ");
            course = input.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.print("Enter your year level: ");/// 1 to 4
        yearLevel  = input.nextInt();

        while((yearLevel<4 || yearLevel>1) )
        {
            System.out.print("you entered wrong year level(re-enter):");
            yearLevel  = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("Enter your age: ");
        age  = input.nextInt();

        while((age>=16) )
        {
            System.out.print("you entered wrong year level(re-enter):");
            yearLevel  = input.nextInt();
        }


    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Student Information");
    System.out.printf("%s (%c)\n", name, gender);
    System.out.printf("%d years old\n", age);
    System.out.println(course + "-" + yearLevel);



}
```

Comment: Which variable does the error message refer to? Also, are you sure your course reading logic is correct?

Comment: The only error spotted so far is your last 5 `System.out.print` statements is not inside any method neither main method. Try compile it using other IDE or simply using _command prompt_

Comment: no I'm not sure :( please help me . the error refer to the "String name;"

Comment: how would I use it using command prompt ?

Comment: @emm forget about it. just move your second last closing bracket into the end of your code lines.

Comment: i already did it , but now it has a problem with the
System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Student Information");
    System.out.printf("%s (%c)\n", name, gender);
    System.out.printf("%d years old\n", age);
    System.out.println(course + "-" + yearLevel);

Comment: @All: Strange that every answer got a down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the println statements are outside the main. Code should be like so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class information {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name ;
        String course;
        char gender;
        int yearLevel;
        int age;

        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        name  = input.nextLine();


        System.out.print("Enter your gender [M/F]: ");
        gender  = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

        while(gender!= 'M' && gender!= 'F'){
            System.out.println("Error: type only M or F");
            System.out.println("Re-enter your gender [M/F]: ");
            gender  = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        }


        System.out.print("Enter your course: "); // BSCS, BSIT or BSIS
        course  = input.nextLine();

        while( course.equals("BSCS") || course.equals("BSIT") || course.equals("BSIS")){
            System.out.println("Error: type only BSCS,BSIT, or BSIS");
            System.out.println("Re-enter your course: ");
            course = input.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.print("Enter your year level: ");/// 1 to 4
        yearLevel  = input.nextInt();

        if(!(yearLevel<=4 && yearLevel>=1) )
        {
            System.out.print("you entered wrong year level(re-enter):");
            yearLevel  = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("Enter your age: ");
        age  = input.nextInt();

        while(!(age>=16) )
        {
            System.out.print("you entered wrong age(re-enter):");
            yearLevel  = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Student Information");
        System.out.printf("%s (%c)\n", name, gender);
        System.out.printf("%d years old\n", age);
        System.out.println(course + "-" + yearLevel);

        input.close();
    }

}
```

Also your while loop (for the year level) has a logic error...

Comment: The while loop should be: `if(!(yearLevel<=4 && yearLevel>=1) )`

Comment: And now the guy who downvoted all answers should comment.

Comment: @Ravinder The question is about the 'local variable is never read' warning. Few of these answers even begin to address it.

Comment: Actually @EJP, I don't know why you down voted everyone's answers, since even though the author said "local variable is never read", that was not the case for the code that he actually posted. The errors the poster had were firstly, he did not call the `close` method on the Scanner "input", and the other errors were the print statements being outside the main class. Please, please don't down vote peoples answers if they actually help the poster. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only error is that the statements

```
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Student Information");
System.out.printf("%s (%c)\n", name, gender);
System.out.printf("%d years old\n", age);
System.out.println(course + "-" + yearLevel);
```

should be inside the `main` method rather than the class block

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. It's about the 'local variable name is never read' warning.

Comment: The code is producing the error for the `name` variable since the `System.out` is required to reference that variable

Comment: @EJP: What is this `while(course.equals...` ?

Comment: Given I was the first to mention this I'll re-instate this answer :)

Comment: @EJP, you should not have down voted this one. Although he did not answer the question, he did point out there are errors and yes I found these same errors. I'm going to up vote because this answer did help the user.

Answer (score -1):

It must be on the `name` variable.

You have something assigned to it. But you have not used it anywhere else after assigning it a value. As it is unused, IDE's *just inform* you that it is not used.

The other main reason is you have the `print` statements out of the method in which the `name` variable is defined. Move them into the method and the warning should go.

Change :

```
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Student Information");
    System.out.printf("%s (%c)\n", name, gender);
    System.out.printf("%d years old\n", age);
    System.out.println(course + "-" + yearLevel);

}
```

To:

```
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Student Information");
        System.out.printf("%s (%c)\n", name, gender);
        System.out.printf("%d years old\n", age);
        System.out.println(course + "-" + yearLevel);

    } // main
} // class
```

Answer (score -4):

The real question is why you are setting the variable but never using its value. If you don't really need it, just remove it. If you do need it, evidently you have left something out of your program.

Comment: I really need it . This is one of my requirement in school and I don't understand programming at all :(

Comment: Need it for what? What are you supposed to do with it when you get it? Shouldn't you be printing it?

Comment: no I'll pass it through the computer . I need it for school

Comment: Your code only writes it. It doesn't read it. You are missing a `println()` for it. If you're not supposed to print it, ignore the warning.

Comment: I guess different IDE may show different error/warning

Comment: @Baby Of course, but I don't see what that has to do with the question, or this answer. The meaning of this specific warning is perfectly clear.

Comment: @EJP ah its been 1year++ and I didnt remember i've wrote on your post. I didnt downvote btw :)